# Jira - JQL "WAS" Operator

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

Im trying to search for all the issues assigned to an user, but no results are being returned and i cant figure out why.

My JQL is the following:

```
project = MYPROJECT and assignee was joaoalves
```

In the [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-WAS) it says:

*The "WAS" operator is used to find issues that currently have, or previously had, the specified value for the specified field.
(Note: This operator can be used with the Assignee, Fix Version, Priority,  Reporter, Resolution and Status fields only.)*

I have an issue assigned to the user joaoalves, but when i search with the JQL above no issues are returned.

But if run the following JQL the issue is returned:

```
project = MYPROJECT and assignee = joaoalves
```

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

It works in my instance, and return issues that currently or previously assign to me. Which version of JIRA are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Assignee was will return the issues which were previously assignee to tat user and current tickets which are present on that user.

Answer (score 1):

Try in conjunction with the "DURING" clause and specify a timeframe. Like this -

```
project = MYPROJECT and assignee was joaoalves DURING ('2017-04-16 23:59', '2017-04-19 23:59')
```

See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/blog/2015/07/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql

Answer (score -1):

The was operator is looking for issues where the assignee was joaoalves but is currently not that user.

Comment: well in the docs it says: "The "WAS" operator is used to find issues that currently have, or previously had, the specified value for the specified field." - So it must return the issues that have or had joaoalves as assignee